# Fetch children of nested tree first

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have a table (let's call it `entries`) that looks like this:

```
id  parent_id
1   0
2   1
3   2
4   1
5   4
6   5
7   4
8   1
```

As a tree, this looks something like this (where the number is the `id`):

```
- 1
    - 2
        - 3
    - 4
        - 5
            - 6
        - 7
    - 8
```

I want to get an array of these IDs starting from the inner most child and working its way up.

The output should be:

```
[3, 2, 6, 5, 7, 4, 8, 1]
```

I'm using [Laravel 5.2](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent).

Comment: Whats the logic behind that tree. Your question seems to be pretty vague. What you have tried so far? Post your attempts

Comment: I have no idea how I would go about doing this logically. All I've done so far is `$results = Entry::all();`.

Comment: This would be the good logic, But you need to explain more about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're trying to do is called [**depth first in order traversal**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal). It can be accomplished by iterating over the leaf nodes of each parent node recursively until you have reached a node with no leaves.

Depending on the data structure you're using to store this data in PHP the approach can vary. For example, using an array (*like the one in the example below*) might look something like this...

```
$tree = [
    1 => [
        2 => [
            3 => [],
        ],
        4 => [
            5 => [
                6 => [],
            ],
            7 => [],
        ],
        8 => [],
    ]
];


function depthFirstTraversal(Array $nodes) {
    foreach($nodes as $node => $children) {
        if (!$children) {
            return $node;
        }
        echo depthFirstTraversal($children);
        echo $node;
    }
}

depthFirstTraversal($tree);

//Output would be 32657481
```

You could do the same thing with objects, as well, where the object specifies the node value and children array as properties instead of using the array key as the parent node and the children as its value like above.

Comment: I leaned about this in college, I was just trying to recall the name of theory.

Comment: Should be outputted as an array.

Comment: Sure you can return an array from that function instead of printing the results directly. Just replace `echo` with an array push and pass along the array :)